# Site has a banner linking to a specific page that's on multipule pages. How do I see which pages click to it and track any transactions from it?

Tags: google, google-analytics, reporting

New-ish GA user here after taking over tasks from a recently departed colleague.

I received a request to track traffic, clicks and product revenue for a banner (a static image) that's featured on multiple pages. They want to know which page gave the best results.

Let's say the banner links to the URL "website.com/products/product123" and it's on the below pages:

"website.com/home"
"website.com/home/NeatStuff"
"website.com/home/OtherThings"

I was trying to look at both Behavior Flow and Events Flow and specifying "website.com/products/product123" but that only shows product123 as the starting page and I couldn't make sense of following interactions (it listed the same page in all steps).

Is there a way to lookup the products123 page, and see how many users came from the other pages? I was also asked to track the Add to Cart event and checkout activity ("website.com/shoppingcart" then "website.com/checkout") but this part may be tricky as only one tracking tag was used for all banners.

An help is appreciated!